# Want read only buffer that only copies data from host to device

Tags: opencl

I am creating a buffer using `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR`.

I only want to copy memory one way, from host to device.

I am using `clEnqueueMapBuffer` to get a host pointer, and `clEnqueueUnmapBuffer`
to copy the data to device.

When I call `clEnqueueMapBuffer`, does this trigger a copy of memory from device to host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `CL_MAP_WRITE`, then it will likely incur a device to host memory copy. The spec says:

> The pointer returned by `clEnqueueMap{Buffer | Image}` is guaranteed to contain the latest bits in the region being mapped when the `clEnqueueMap{Buffer | Image}` command has completed

If you are using OpenCL 1.2, then you can use `CL_MAP_WRITE_INVALIDATE_REGION` to indicate that you intend to overwrite the entire mapped region from the host, which means that the runtime need not copy any data from the device to the host.

Comment: The answer is clear for CL1.2, but for pre CL1.2, the answer is not clear. The spec does not define what happens when you map for `CL_MAP_WRITE`. And as a personal experience, it forces the behavior of CL1.2 of `CL_MAP_WRITE_INVALIDATE_REGION`. So, no, there is no extra copy from device to host. This is why in pre CL1.2, the flags `CL_MAP_WRITE | CL_MAP_READ` are allowed, but in CL1.2 they are forbidden to be together.

Comment: Thank you, jprice and DarkZeros!  Yes, I am using 1.2.

Comment: It seems to me that if the buffer is created with CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, then you would never want a device to host copy, because the device would never do anything to change the data in the buffer. So, the host should already have the data.

Comment: Note: I abandoned clEnqueueMap/Unmap in favour of clEnqueueWriteBuffer, because it is way faster on my platform (AMD HD7700)

Comment: @DarkZeros - Are you certain that `CL_MAP_WRITE | CL_MAP_READ` combination is not allowed in OpenCL 1.2? Spec does not seem to support this notion: https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html; the read/write combination also works correctly with NVIDIA and AMD GPUs in my experience.

Comment: @void_ptr is right; you can use `CL_MAP_WRITE | CL_MAP_READ` together but you may not combine `CL_MAP_WRITE_INVALIDATE` with either. The spec sentence "CL_MAP_READ or CL_MAP_WRITE and CL_MAP_WRITE_INVALIDATE_REGION are mutually exclusive." should be read with parenthesis around the "or" part <g>.